# Joining meshes issue

Tags: mesh, sculpting

When I combine two meshes one of the meshes changes shape for some reason. Not sure if It has to do with bones or not but Id like to fix this. Can someone explain how to fix this issue.

Comment: Could you please show a bit of the scene? Are there any modifiers on the two objects?

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add more information on how you set up your project. [Add images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) that might help others understand the problem.